# Why does using an assignment expression in a loop condition store a bool value?

Tags: python, python-assignment-expression

This code stores your favorite foods in a list, but the input turns into a bool type character. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
foods=list()
while food := input("what food do you like?: ") != "quit":
    foods.append(food)
print(foods)
```

Comment: `while (food := input("what food do you like?: ")) != "quit":`?

Comment: just put some parenthesis, `(food := input(...)) != ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is comparing input and "quit". When you enter kl and kgh, they are not equal to "quit" and food is `True` and it gets appended to foods. When you enter "quit" as the input, quit is equal to quit and food is `False` and the expression become `while False` so the loop breaks. Instead, do this code:

```
foods=[]
while True:
    food=input("what food do you like: ")
    if food=="quit":
        break
    else:
        foods.append(food)
print(foods)
```

Answer (score 2):

That happens because of the operation precedence. The expression

```
food := input("what food do you like?: ") != "quit"
```

is read as

```
food := (input("what food do you like?: ") != "quit")
```

which is what makes `food` a bool. You can fix it by adding parentheses:

```
while (food := input("what food do you like?: ")) != "quit":
   foods.append(food)
```